# Finding an item with id in Room db and receiving it in a ViewModel

Tags: android, android-asynctask, viewmodel, android-room

I have an app that represents list of user notes in `MainActivity`.  I want to go to `SecondActivity` when the user clicks on one of the items. In `SecondActivity` the contents of the note should be displayed.
I need to get item's id and send it to `SecondActivity`. I can do it with this query:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM notes WHERE id == :id")
    Note getNote(int id);
```

But I don't know what to do in `ViewModel`. I created a class that extends `AsyncTask` that runs getNote() method. I have to return this note by `AsyncTask` but because this class doesn't create in an Activity I can't use `onPostResult`.
after create `AsyncTask` what I have to do?

this is my ViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private NoteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;


    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllWords() {
        return allNotes;
    }
    public void insert(Note note) {
        repository.insert(note);
    }
    public void delete(Note note) {
        repository.deleteNote(note);
    }

}
```

and this is Note:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    private String title;
    private String text;

    public Note(String title, String text) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting a complete `Note` object inside your ViewModel? if so, then inside the `MainActivity` where you are performing onClick, use your ViewModel object and access the `id` of that particular note and attach with the `SecondActivity` Intent.  
Please add your ViewModel file to the question.

Comment: post updated. no. Note class is a separate class